# Redirect to a single URL based on the date stated in other URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, date, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do this,

- Use a single URL to display a different image based on the date. For example, `https://example.com/imageoftheday/`
- I have a series of images already uploaded. Their URLs are like `https://example.com/images/2022/01/22/image.jpg` and `https://example.com/images/2022/01/23/image.jpg`
- I wish that on the day, say Jan 22, `https://example.com/images/2022/01/22/image.jpg` will appear at `https://example.com/imageoftheday/` and if it's Jan 23, `https://example.com/images/2022/01/23/image.jpg` will appear.

Is that possible?

Comment: The typical approach for this is to use a routing script: you internally rewrite the requests to some script , usually a php script is used. That script decides what resource should be the response to the request and sends out the payload along with matching http headers. This offers flexibility and you can easily adapt or even extend your logic, for example to add request authorization or a more complex logic at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Apache/`.htaccess` then there are various `TIME_XXXXX` server variables available with current date and time information so you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite to *unconditionally* rewrite a request for `/imageoftheday/` to the current `/images/<year>/<month>/<day>/image.jpg`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^imageoftheday/$ images/%{TIME_YEAR}/%{TIME_MON}/%{TIME_DAY}/image.jpg [L]
```

If you want to first test that the image exists before rewriting and display a `default.jpg` image when it doesn't then you could do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/%{TIME_YEAR}/%{TIME_MON}/%{TIME_DAY}/image.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^imageoftheday/$ images/%{TIME_YEAR}/%{TIME_MON}/%{TIME_DAY}/image.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^imageoftheday/$ images/default.jpg [L]
```